# What are the consequences of setting the SupportedImageReturnTypes to MIME in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, rest

I am currently exploring using the ExportMap function on the rest endpoint of a Cached Map Service.( I want to export only some layer within a Mapservice).

I have found that if you change the SupportedImageReturnTypes to MIME of a mxd based mapservice, you can export sublayers of a cached mapservice. (As an aside, you can't do this, if it is a msd based mapservice; even if you change SupportedImageReturnTypes from MIME+url to MIME, the exported image has all the layers. I think it directly returns the cached image.)

The [ArcGIS Server help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3.1/dotNet/cfg_file_service.htm) mentions that this setting

> ...Specifies whether images will be
>   returned as MIME data or written to
>   disk (MIME + URL). If you choose URL,
>   you must have a server directory
>   specified for the configuration.

I have tested this out and saw that if the setting was set to MIME+url, then a single temp png file is created in the output director, but it changes as the user pans the map & is deleted within a few seconds.

This is different from the cache, which remains on disk.

I am wondering if it is a good idea to set the setting to MIME, or would it have some consequence on performance.

Does anyone have any experience with this setting?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you want the image to be sent to you directly or if you want to get it your self. In case of MIME amount of information sent might get a bit bigger. But if you let ArcGIS Server create an image on disk you get an overhead of disk-IO. I only tested ExportMap against dynamic map servcies so I don't know if there is any difference between MIME and disk in cached services.