# ArcGIS Server output directory to mime or not to mime

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the consequences of setting the SupportedImageReturnTypes to MIME in ArcGIS Server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/what-are-the-consequences-of-setting-the-supportedimagereturntypes-to-mime-in-arc)

What are the downsides of changing a map service to MIME only? The developer summit perf video says that it is faster and scales better just using MIME.

What things break from not having the image written to disk if anything?

List of broken things:

1. WMS
2. WFS
3. WCS

I'm also noticing when setting layer definitions the js api posts if the get request is too long and tries to send back the url instead of the mime type. if it's mime only the url json prop is empty.

With arcobjects, if you try doing IMapServerLayout.ExportLayout the url property isn't set but the mimeData property is set.

Comment: Do you have a link to the video?  Is it the same as [this pdf](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit10/papers/tech/performance_factors_and_optimization_devsummit_2010.pdf)?

Comment: @kirk here's a post with the video link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12500/improving-map-service-performance/12503#12503 that pdf looks similar. but not quite exact.

Comment: @mapperz this is not the same question as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/what-are-the-consequences-of-setting-the-supportedimagereturntypes-to-mime-in-arc - his is specific to rest where as this is a more open ended question.

Comment: I would like this re-opened.  Already good answers, but no conclusion as of yet.

Comment: @Simon did you vote to reopen?

Comment: i flagged it to be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that the dev summit video says MIME only scales better - I just went through the ESRI .NET administration class and the course materials say MIME only is *less* scalable because the output images are streamed to the client as network packets, and the server must process all of these packets.

Is also says that WCS will work with MIME only, but maybe this is available at 10 only (I see you tagged as 9.3.1).  WMS and WFS will not work, as they require a virtual directory.

Comment: In a simplistic view, MIME should scale better seeing how the rendered image is never written to the disk.  Data is rendered and returned directly to the client, vs. URL request which has to be written to the disk.  Larger performance impact will be noticed if your virtual output directory is not on a local drive.

Comment: That could be, and it makes sense - I was just providing information from the ESRI training materials.

Comment: I ran across a similar statement to yours from ESRI too, where they suggested MIME only will break down as the load increases.  Yet they contradicted themselves in the presentation Steve mentions.